# API de bateria do Cordova não funciona

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, mobile

Eu Estou tentando usar a API do cordova BatteryStatus e não estou conseguindo, nem no emulador do Intel XDK, nem no debug no meu Android e nem quando gero um .APK. Simplesmente não acontece nada quando executo.

Basicamente to usando esse código encontrado em http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#batterystatus:

```
    window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);

function onBatteryStatus(info) {
    // Handle the online event
    console.log("Level: " + info.level + " isPlugged: " + info.isPlugged); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual o resultado esperado?

É preciso entender que o Cordova não informa o level da bateria sobre requisição.
Somente quando o evento `batterystatus` for disparado que você terá algum retorno.

Ou seja, você só terá o `level` da bateria quando receber um status de bateria fraca, `level` alterado, de cabo de energia conectado (Ou qualquer outro status de bateria).

Caso precise de um plugin que te informe o `level` da bateria a qualquer momento pode conferir esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478704/how-to-get-battery-level-in-cordova-2-9-when-it-need).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa esperar o evento `deviceready` do Cordova. Tente da seguinte forma:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.addEventListener("batterylow", onBatteryLow, false);
}

// Handle the batterylow event
function onBatteryLow(info) {
    alert("Battery Level Low " + info.level + "%"); 
}
```